# Evaluate the Expected Value. Black and White balls in a bag.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, balls-in-bins

A bag contains $5$ black balls and $7$ white balls. Balls are drawn of the bag e organized in a row of $12$ balls. Every configuration has the same probability of happening.

For example, if we set $B =  Black$ and $W = White$, one possible configuration is 
$B \ W \ B \ B \ W \ W \ W \ B \ W \ W \ B \ W$.

Going through this row from left to right, whats is the expected value of the number of black balls that are immediately followed for a white ball?

My attempt: I think I should enumerate tha black balls ($k = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$) and define $X_k$ as follows:

$X_k =\left\{\begin{array}{rc}
1,&\mbox{if ball $k$ is followed by a white ball}\\
0, \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.
$

I'm having some trouble to evaluate $\mathbb{E}(X_k)$. Once I do that, then $\mathbb{E}(A) = \sum_{k=1}^{5} \mathbb{E}(X_k)$, where $A$ is the event of a black ball being followed by a white ball. And I also know that $\mathbb{E}(X_k) = \mathbb{E}(X_1), \forall k \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Comment: I suggest you break the number into a sum of $11$ indicators $Y_i$, where $Y_i$ are indicating the $i$-th position being black and $i+1$-th position being white, $i = 1, 2, \ldots, 11$.

Answer (score 0):

Because $\mathbb{E}(A) = \sum_{k=1}^{5} \mathbb{E}(X_k)$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_k) = \mathbb{E}(X_1), \forall k \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$, we have $\mathbb{E}(A)=5\mathbb{E}(X_{1})$. 
$P(X_{1}=1)=\frac{7}{5+7}=\frac{7}{12}$.
Thus $\mathbb{E}(X_{1})=\frac{7}{12}$ and $\mathbb{E}(A)=\frac{35}{12}$.